# shifting right in for loop over indices in python

Tags: python

I had a list `[a,b,c,d]` in python and I shifted it to the left by using, for loop over the indices and my result was `[b,c,d,a]`.

Now I have planned to shift it to the right and I assume the result will be `[d,a,b,c]`, but I can't able to write the code for it.

Can anyone suggest me with the code and concept?

This was my code for shifting to the left.

```
def shift_left(L):
    first_item = L[0]
    for i in range (1, len(L)):
        L[i-1] = L[i] 
    L[-1] = first_item
```

Answer (score 7):

It's best to use a [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) for this:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d']
>>>
>>> v = deque(l)
>>> v.rotate(1)
>>> v
deque(['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
>>>
>>> v = deque(l)
>>> v.rotate(-1)
>>> v
deque(['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'])
```

You can convert back to a list via `list(v)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `pop` and `insert`:

```
def shift_right(l):
    l.insert(0, l.pop())
```

`pop` removes and returns the last item in a list, and `insert` inserts an item at an index.

Answer (score 1):

If your elements are of a single type, consider making a NumPy array and "rolling" it:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(my_list)
shifted_left = np.roll(arr, -1)
shifted_right = np.roll(arr, 1)
```